# return var-type variable

Tags: c#

I has some method, for example:

```
    public VAR GetAllPosts()
    {
        var post = from p in _db.Posts  select p;
        return post;
    }
```

How return var-type variable?

Comment: Can't be done. See what type the var is and return that, or change your query to return a type you can use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your code, you know it's going to be a enumeration of Posts, so return

```
public IEnumerable<Posts> GetAllPosts()
    {
        var post = from p in _db.Posts  select p;
        return post;
    }
```

or

```
public IEnumerable<Posts> GetAllPosts()
    {
        return from p in _db.Posts  select p;
    }
```

If you want to go hardcore you could use something like this, this is a generic type of T, you have to call the method with the desired type and inside it validate the type and do what you like.

```
  public List<T> GetData<T>()
  {
      //Validate the type and do something
      if (typeof(T) == typeof(MyClass))
      {
         List<MyClass> lst = new List<MyClass>();
         lst.Add(new MyClass { ClassProperty = "Value" });

         return lst as List<T>;
     }
     else // do something else
     {
       return null;
     }
   }
```

To call this method you pass the correct type

```
List<MyClass> list = GetData<MyClass>();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 9):

You can have it `object`, however you still will have to cast it to use it appropriately. `dynamic` is another option, but might be more trouble than its worth.

I think what you might want is `IQueryable<T>` where `T` is the type of `Posts`.

Answer (score 5):

`var` is not a type, so can not be returned.

If you  are uncertain about return type, return `object` (like Daniel suggests), if it can be more then one type, return thier base type, if any.

In your concrete case, *seems*, that you are trying to return `IEnumerable<T>` of the objects in `_db.Posts`